# PopOS 20.10: Gnome slow and laggy

Tags: gnome3, chrome, intel-graphics, pop-os, lag

## Introduction

Recently I accomplished a brand new installation of `PopOS 20.10 standard image` (not NVIDIA one).
I have `Intel UHD Graphics 620` (rev. 7) / `i7-8650U` installed.

## Problem statement

I noticed a `very laggy UI`, just the same way when you don't have Intel graphics drivers installed on your Windows machine.

I.e. when you view animations while surfing the web in your browser.

## Solution

Just move to `Wayland` from `X11` and that should resolve the issue for `100%` *(that did for me)*.

## Guideline

```bsh
# Edit GDM3 configuration
# set (or add this entry if missing) WaylandEnable=true
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
# Restart the GDM3 daemon
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

Now you should see `PopOS on Wayland` on the login screen under `gear button`. Choose that option.
[image]

## Check which display protocol is being used

```bsh
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

## References

[LinuxConfig](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-20-04-desktop)

Comment: Welcome, You can post the solution as an answer separately from the question.

Comment: thanks for the tip!, I have Intel® UHD Graphics P630 and this has improved the perfomance (if only slightly)

Comment: Previously I had WaylandEnable=false. Setting WaylandEnable=true broke everything: No login menu anymore, just a blank gray screen, and the (System76 laptop) touchpad no longer worked.  Switching it back to false meant that I could log in again, but Gnome is back to being super slow.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the X environment:

`alt+F2` and then `r` and press `Enter`

also check this Reddit [System freezes and performance loss after System Sleep](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/kkfkp9/system_freezes_and_performance_loss_after_system/)